# I am unable to understand how LSTM is taking my data as input

Tags: neural-networks, lstm, keras

```
X_train.shape, X_test.shape, Y_train.shape, Y_test.shape
((2457, 55, 26), (820, 55, 26), (2457, 3), (820, 3))
```

X_train is like having 2457 samples of matrix of size 55x26. 55 is data in timeseries represented in 26 columns(My device from which data was collected had 26 channels).

I have a sequential model having the first layer as LSMT:

```
model1.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(100))
```

Now my doubt is how is LSTM layer taking is receiving input as 1x55x26 right?
Also, LSTM `units` is `100`, so how does each unit accept data? are all 100 units used or there is some sort of zero paddings for unused units in LSTM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An LSTM takes a time series as an "example," or "instance." The word "input" is overloaded, because an LSTM can be viewed as operating on a single timestep at a time or multiple examples of multiple time steps, or several different segments of the same time series, depending exactly on what you mean by "input."

There are 26 channels and 100 units, so the LSTM **layer's** weight matrices are $26 \times 100$. Matrix multiplication is used to take the 26 channels and represent them as 100 channels.

If you want to think in terms of **units** instead of layers, then each of the 100 units has a vector of 26 weights, so that the dot-product with the 26 channels for one time-step represents the 26 input channels in a single channel. Then each of the 100 units has its own channel.

All 100 units are used -- there's no padding or anything.

Comment: Thank you for your response. So each unit will receive a 55x26 matrix as input or something else happens?

Comment: I've made an edit that should make this clear.

Comment: Thanks a lot...